# How to efficiently perform a dictionary merge?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, merge, dynamic-programming

For a problem I am solving, I have a list of dictionaries. The problem involves multiple queries of the form `merge(a, b, c)`. Merging means, in the result, the count for the common keys is added/subtracted and uncommon keys (and their values) are appended as is.

I am currently using Python's `collection.Counter` to represent the dictionaries and perform the merging as follows:

```py
def merge(a, b, c):
    counter_a, counter_b, counter_c = DICTLIST[a],DICTLIST[b],DICTLIST[c]
    total = counter_a + counter_b - counter_c # Type collections.Counter
    return total
```

Although this is a convenient solution, in the problem, there can be up to 10**5 such queries. On such a scale, using this approach is too slow. Is there a better approach to solving this?

*NOTE:* Pre-computation of the merge queries is not practical as the number of possible inputs is very large.

*Example:*

```py
DICTLIST[a] = Counter({1:5,2:10})
DICTLIST[b] = Counter({2:10,3:20})
DICTLIST[c] = Counter({1:2})
merge(a,b,c) # Expected Output: {1:3, 2:20, 3:20}
```

Comment: an example demonstrating merge fun would help us better to understand you question

Comment: What do you know about keys?

Comment: @SachinPatel Added in edit

Comment: Where does `1:3` come from?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal The count for key '1' is 5 in the first Counter and '2' in the last. Since the aggregation is done as a + b - c, the count is subtracted '1': (5-2 = 3)

Comment: @MBo In the context of this problem, the dictionary stores counts of the prime factors of a number. Thus the keys are prime factors of a given number and the corresponding value represents the power of that prime in a number's prime factorization.

Comment: So keys are integers, and their range and number are very limited (until you need to factorize huge numbers)?

Comment: @MBo The numbers to be factorized are less than 10**6. However, the prime factorization has been pre-computed and the corresponding Counter can be retrieved in O(1).

Comment: So you can use simple list of integers (or numpy array)  of length 1000 to store prime counts and operate with counters as fast as possible (you don't need universalism of dictionary-based Counter and corresponding overhead for hash calculation etc).

Comment: Also simple multiplication/dividing of the numbers itselves (without factorization) might be quite faster (cannot be sure without knowing of the main problem)

Comment: @Mbo But what about a case when the number is a prime greater than 1000? The prime count of such a value won't be accommodated in the  list of size 1000.

Comment: Don't know consize solution for this case (while 10^6 length array is quite reliable).

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
def mergeDict(dict1, dict2):
    dict3 = {**dict1, **dict2}
    for key, value in dict3.items():
    if key in dict1 and key in dict2:
        dict3[key] = value + dict1[key]
    return dict3
```

Then you can call like this -

```
# Create first dictionary
dict1 = {1:5,2:10}

# Create second dictionary
dict2 = {2:10,3:20}

# Create third dictionary
dict3 = {1:-2}

dict4 = mergeDict(dict3, mergeDict(dict1, dict2))
```

Please note I have **"-2"** in the third dict for the subtraction logic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use **kwargs here

```
x={1:5,2:10}
y={2:10,3:20}
z={**x, **y}
```

if you further want to optimize the performance as there are multiple queries you should use "caching + dictionary" because lookup table is always faster than any operation

Answer (score 0):

My first instinct is to look for something like the Javascript "spread" operator for python:

https://mlpipes.com/object-spread-operator-python/

Example here:

```
old_dict = {'hello': 'world', 'foo': 'bar'}
new_dict = {**old_dict, 'foo': 'baz'}
```

For your code, you should try something like:

```
DICTLIST[d] = {**a,**b,**c}
```